# Java Basics pulling the values

Tags: java, jsp

i have two fields integer values gross Salary and deductions and i am calculating net salary from that(Gross-deductions).I do these steps in one class and i need to set the net salary in my action class to show as result in my jsp page.I have all the setter and getter methods in place.
How can i achieve that.

Please Help.Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have the setter method in place, can't you just call it (passing in the calculated net salary)??

Comment: We won't guess what your issue is, plus there are plenty of JSP tutorials around. Please follow them before asking about the basics.

Comment: Could you please add your complete code?

Answer (score 0):

After you calculate the salary,why don't you pass the information as request parameters Variables to the jsp page.
Following is an example of jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
Salary: <%= request.getParameter("salary") %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because this code will open the door for Cross-Site Scripting.